# Does MS Edge continue IE versions?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge

As far as I know IE max version is 11 and Edge min version is 12.
Does it mean that IE support is dropped, Edge is its successor and it is safe to assume that their versions will never overlap?

Comment: This isn't a programming question so isn't on-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

IE and MS Edge are different products. MS Edge was developed using totally new platform. So MS Edge is not dependent on IE in any way and MS Edge is not a successor of IE.

At present, only the most recent version of IE is supported which is IE 11.

In future, IE will not get any new feature updates but it will get security updates.

Yes, It is safe to assume that their versions will never overlap because both products are different.

References:

(1) [Support for older versions of Internet Explorer ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support)

(2) [Lifecycle FAQ—Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454/lifecycle-faq-internet-explorer)

(3) [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge)